# Nested Where In Eloquent Not Working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Hi I have the following code in my lumen app:

```
$schedules = TravelSchedule::with(["route", "tickets.passenger"])
->whereHas("buses", function($query) use ($bus) {
    $query->where("bus_id", $bus->id);
})
->whereHas("route")
->whereHas("tickets", function($query) {
    $query->whereHas("invoice", function($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull("verified_at")
            ->whereNull("cancelled_at");
    })
    ->whereHas("passenger", function($query) {
        $query->whereNull("departed_at")
            ->whereNotNull("arrived_at");
    });
})->get();
```

I noticed the `whereNull` and `whereNotNull` functions do not work when I run the code, I took them out and still had the same result returned.  Does eloquent not support this kind of nested queries? How can I rewrite this query so that it checks for null and not null fields on those relationships?

This is the generated sql:

```
select * from `travel_schedules`
where exists (select * from `buses`
  inner join `travel_schedule_bus`
    on `buses`.`id` = `travel_schedule_bus`.`bus_id`
    where `travel_schedules`.`id` = `travel_schedule_bus`.`travel_schedule_id`
    and `bus_id` = 137
    and `buses`.`deleted_at` is null)
and exists (select * from `travel_routes`
            where `travel_schedules`.`travel_route_id` = `travel_routes`.`id`
            and `travel_routes`.`deleted_at` is null)
and exists (select * from `sales_invoice_tickets`
            where `travel_schedules`.`id` = `sales_invoice_tickets`.`schedule_id`
            and exists (select * from `sales_invoices`
                        where `sales_invoice_tickets`.`sales_invoice_id` = `sales_invoices`.`id`
                        and `verified_at` is not null
                        and `cancelled_at` is null)
            and `sales_invoice_tickets`.`deleted_at` is null)
and exists (select * from `sales_invoice_tickets`
            where `travel_schedules`.`id` = `sales_invoice_tickets`.`schedule_id`
            and exists (select * from `passengers`
                        where `sales_invoice_tickets`.`id` = `passengers`.`ticket_id`
                        and `departed_at` is null
                        and `arrived_at` is not null)
            and `sales_invoice_tickets`.`deleted_at` is null)
and `travel_schedules`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: have u checked the data, is it actually null / not null ? not empty strings perhapos

Comment: Yes I have. Values are correct.